# How to code and compile Pascal using Code Block?

Tags: codeblocks, pascal

Can I using CodeBlocks to code, compile, and debug Pascal file?
If possible, how to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, CodeBlocks is primarily a C/C++ IDE.

The [featurelist](http://www.codeblocks.org/features) of CodeBlocks tells:

> Multiple compiler support:
>       GCC (MingW / GNU GCC)
>       MSVC++
>       clang
>       Digital Mars
>       Borland C++ 5.5
>       Open Watcom
>       ...and more

Some other languages are supported with syntax highlighting.
But you could try to configure your own compiler settings in

> "Settings -> Compiler and debugger -> Global compiler settings ->
>   [your compiler] -> Toolchain executables"

But you'll definitely have to install a separate pascal compiler before.

**If you're looking for a free opensource pascal IDE, you should definitely take a look at [lazarus](http://www.lazarus-ide.org/)**

Answer (score 2):

According to http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Languages_supported_by_Code::Blocks_lexers CodeBlocks supports Pascal. I agree, however, that Lazarus is an excellent IDE for Object Pascal.

Comment: I tried and CodeBlocks supported just syntax highlighting. No debug / compiler support. If you want to compile your code from CodeBlocks You have to take the steps I described in my answer.